# How to fill spinner with data from room, with MVVM architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I want to know the best practice/way to fill any Spinner with data from room db.

I also want to use ViewModel and LiveData (then I'll move to StateFlow!), but I'm confused with the correct order defining variables.

first I have this in the view model:

```
val aniosLiveData = anioRepository.anios.asLiveData() // return  LiveData<List<Anio>>
```

then on the fragment, first the viewmodel declaration:

```
private val ensayosViewModel: EnsayosViewModel by viewModels()
```

then, in onViewCreated() I have a block with the binding elements:

```
 binding.apply {
        recyclerViewEnsayos.apply {
            adapter = ensayosAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager( requireContext())
            setHasFixedSize(true)
        }
        spinnerAnio.apply {
            adapter = aniosAdapter  // <- Spinner adapter
        }
    }
```

I override onCreate() to define an observer, and then I put this lines:

```
       ensayosViewModel.aniosLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {spinnerData ->
        aniosAdapter = ArrayAdapter<Anio>(requireContext(), R.layout.spinner_text_item, spinnerData)
    })
```

Where/When do I need to declare "aniosAdapter" ? like this: ?

```
 //At class level
 private lateinit var aniosAdapter : ArrayAdapter<Anio>
```

Is this the correct way ?
There is another ?? more simpler ?

Thanks in advance!
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you need reference to the `aniosAdapter` outside of the lifecycle hook, I would recommend using a `private lateinit var` as you alluded. While you are initializing the `spinnerAnio`'s adapter correctly at first, it's not going retroactively recognize any mutations you make to `aniosAdapter` after the execution of the lifecycle hook. Instead, you're going to need to adjust your `aniosLiveData` observer to appear as such:

```
ensayosViewModel.aniosLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    binding.spinnerAnio.adapter = ArrayAdapter<Anio>(
        requireContext(),
        R.layout.spinner_text_item,
        it
    )
})
```

In the scenario where you do need to reference the `aniosAdapter` outside of the lifecycle hook's scope, your observer would likely look as such in conjunction with the `private lateinit var` you referenced:

```
ensayosViewModel.aniosLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    aniosAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
        requireContext(),
        R.layout.spinner_text_item,
        it
    )

    binding.spinnerAnio.adapter = aniosAdapter
})
```

If you can guarantee that your observer will trigger immidately, `aniosAdapter` would be safe to declare as a `private lateinit var`. If you are unsure, it would be much safer to consider it as an optional field as depicted below. Nice work!

```
private var aniosAdapter: ArrayAdapter<Anio>? = null
```